# How do I create laravel API to access in VueJS framework?

Tags: frameworks, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I need to access data using Laravel 5.4 as API, to access it in vueJS, how can I create API in laravel to access it in VueJS framework?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Are you asking how to make an `api` in laravel? (which is my guess based on your question) If so then you should look into some tutorials or books to learn it.

Comment: @Ragas, yes I found it. thanks. `solved`